# Numbered bookmarks in PDF output from DITA bookmaps with and without parts

Tags: xslt, dita

I am trying to create PDF output with numbered headings using the DITA OT and a custom plugin. By default, the output contains part numbers, chapter numbers and appendix number in the headings and the TOC, but no numbers in the bookmarks. So far, I have managed to number all the remaining topics in the headings and the TOC, like so (the chapter numbers restart in every part):

- bookmap

  - part I

    - chapter 1

      - topic 1.1
      - topic 1.2
    - chapter 2
  - part II

    - chapter 1

However, I cannot get the same numbers for the bookmarks.

I am using the following code (or override) to select the bookmarks that must be numbered:

```
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic ')]" mode="bookmark">
    <xsl:variable name="mapTopicref" select="key('map-id', @id)[1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="topicTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="getNavTitle"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$mapTopicref[@toc = 'yes' or not(@toc)] or
            not($mapTopicref)">
            <fo:bookmark>
                <xsl:attribute name="internal-destination">
                    <xsl:call-template name="generate-toc-id"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:if test="$bookmarkStyle!='EXPANDED'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="starting-state">hide</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <fo:bookmark-title>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($mapTopicref/@class, ' bookmap/part ')">
                            <xsl:call-template name="getChapterPrefix"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($mapTopicref/@class, ' bookmap/appendix ')">
                            <xsl:call-template name="getChapterPrefix"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="contains($mapTopicref/@class, ' bookmap/chapter ')">
                            <xsl:call-template name="getChapterPrefix"/>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($topicTitle)"/>
                </fo:bookmark-title>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="bookmark"/>
            </fo:bookmark>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="bookmark"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I am using the following code to create the numbers (derived from an example in DITA for Print):

```
    <xsl:template name="getChapterPrefix">
    <xsl:variable name="topicType">
        <xsl:call-template name="determineTopicType"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="partsCount">
        <xsl:value-of select="count($map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/part')])"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="containingChapter" select="ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@class, ' topic/topic')][position()=1]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="$containingChapter/@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="topicChapters">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter')]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="topicAppendices">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/appendix')]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="topicParts">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/part')]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="chapterNumber">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$topicChapters/*[@id = $id]">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$partsCount=0"> <!-- Bookmaps without parts work fine -->
                        <xsl:number format="1" value="count($topicChapters/*[@id =$id]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>                           
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise> <!-- This does not work yet. -->
                        <xsl:number format="1" value="count($topicChapters/*[@id =$id]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>                
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$topicAppendices/*[@id = $id]">
                <xsl:number format="A" value="count($topicAppendices/*[@id =$id]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$topicParts/*[@id = $id]">
                <xsl:number format="I" value="count($topicParts/*[@id =$id]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$chapterNumber != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="$chapterNumber"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

With this code, parts, appendices and bookmaps without parts are numbered correctly. However, for bookmaps with parts, chapters are numbered consecutively, which is inconsistent.

- bookmap

  - part I

    - chapter 1

      - topic 1.1
      - topic 1.2
    - chapter 2
  - part II

    - chapter 3

Can anybody help me to correct this?

Comment: Can you provide the source XML? This would make it easier to answer you.

Comment: I have a public gist on https://gist.github.com/SusanneM/

Comment: It would be better if you could incorporate the relevant part(s) into the question to create a [mcve], because links could vanish anytime.

Comment: So when you use `<xsl:copy-of select="$map//*[contains(@class, ' bookmap/chapter')]"/>` to bind the variable `topicChapters` to the copy of the chapters, is there no way to preserve a hierarchy? Aren't those elements you copy there contained in parent elements for the parts so that you should rather copy the parts or transform them to contain the chapters you are interested in? Obviously in your current approach your variable contains a flat list of elements and when you count sibling elements you do end up with all preceding chapters.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I found one way to solve it (which doesn't look very elegant to me, but i works): I just ignore the topicChapters variable when I have a bookmap with parts.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to obtain the result I want. The piece of code that calculates the chapter number for bookmaps with parts was modified als follows:

```
            <!-- If there's something in $topicChapters with an id that matches the id of the
    context node, then I'm inside a chapter. -->
            <xsl:when test="$topicChapters/*[@id = $id]">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$partsCount=0"> <!-- Bookmaps without parts -->
                        <xsl:number format="1" value="count($topicChapters/*[@id =$id]/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>                           
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise> <!-- Bookmaps with parts. -->
                        <xsl:number format="1" value="count(//*[contains(@class,' bookmap/chapter ')][@id =$id]/preceding-sibling::*)"/>                
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
```

This is probably everything but elegant, but then, I'm a tech writer ...